# iOS 11 push-notifications : How to access the payload of a push notification as soon as we receive it?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, swift4, ios11

when the app is in fore ground, with the help of

```
 public func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                        willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                        withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void)
```

this method we can get the payload of push-notification from

```
notification.request.content
```

But when the app is in background, how do we access the payload as soon as we receive notification?

If not, in facebook we won't see notification on notification center sometimes but if you open the app they are available?

Any help will be appreciated!!

Comment: may facebook uses silent notification which has no title and sound and it is directly available in application. Here is some [link](https://medium.com/@m.imadali10/ios-silent-push-notifications-84009d57794c)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to access push directly in your application without knowing to user then you need to use silent push notification.

> When you send a Silent push notification and if app is suspended then the system wakes up or launches your app and puts it into the background running state before calling the method but if the app is killed by user manually then it will not wakeup. They can be used to inform the application of new content without having the user informed. Instead of displaying a notification alert, the application will be awakened in background.

```
JSON payload for Silent Push notifications:

{
    "aps" = {
        "content-available" : 1,
        "sound" : ""
    };
    // You can add custom key-value pair here...
}
```

Here is the [link](https://medium.com/@m.imadali10/ios-silent-push-notifications-84009d57794c) of tutorial.